# Ubuntu 13.04 causes other pcs internet to be slow?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 a few days ago.

Last night I went to a friend's house where we were 5 persons total.
Everyone noticed that the internet was slow - except me. For me it was fast.

So we decided to to a little experiment.We started turning off the laptops to see which was causing the trouble. When I turned off mine, the connection speed was restored for the others! (no one of us was downloading/uploading/cloud synchronizing anything).
Their laptops had Windows, but one of them had Ubuntu 12.10 on a partition. So he booted into it, and still his connection was slow. When I disconnected from the LAN, it was ok.

Today another friend came at my house (running windows) and we are having the same trouble. When I d/c from the LAN it's ok, when I am online *his* internet is slow. So that means that it wasn't a problem with my friend's router (last night).

I am concluding the my pc is causing the trouble. I even downloaded avg for linux to search for viruses - it didn't find anything.

Any ideas what might be the cause? A newly introduced bug?

Note: I checked the monitor program and I wasn't downloading/uploading anything (~1Kbps download, ~0 upload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem and it was driving me nuts, so I installed a fresh copy of 12.04LTS and the same thing was happening. which was weird 'cause that's never happened to me before. I then disabled the proprietary driver for the wireless card, rebooted and no more slowing down my network.  Try that, hopefully it will be your solution as well.

Comment: The solution worked! I removed the proprietory drivers for the WiFi and and everything is as before. Maybe there's a bug in their code.